# How to differentiate multiple classes with the same function

Tags: c++, class, uml, class-diagram

Lets say I have a room with two doors. A central system is controlling both of them. This is done by using sockets. The `DoorController` class has to implement two instances of door. These door classes have an interface to talk to the socket. How do I implement these two classes with the same behaviour in my class diagram so that `DoorController` knows which door he is operating?

Comment: Why socket interfaces is relevante here? And why you can't use the value of a property inside the class etc... Could you provide a simple example of the DoorController implementation?

Comment: "has to implement two instances of door" sounds wrong. I guess you mean "is instantiated twice".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you problem well, you should have one class called `DoorController` and two objects called `door_1` and `door_2`. The class `DoorController` should have a member variable called `ID` and you can then change this member variable in `door_1` and `door_2` with two different values.

Answer (score 0):

I think `DoorController` can have even a list of many doors object. To provide identification for the chosen door, every `Door` object must have an unique `id` - an property.